# How do I get rid of a staged configuration import?

Tags: 8, configuration

I have a staged import that I can't apply and I would like to get rid of it and be clean in my configuration management screen.
How do I get rid of the staged import? Can I go to sync folder and delete the .yml files and the export the current configuration again?
I am extremely nervous about breaking the site.
I know it is saved in the db but I don't want to go in and delete it from there either, unless that is an option.
I wont be able to apply any other import because of this staged one sitting here.

Comment: You oyu have yml files with changes and you want to get ird of them? So stay with current datbase configuration, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you export the configuration again current configuration files should be deleted and new ones will be created with the configuration hold in your database.

Anyway you should make a backup first, just in case. You can use drush for this. Use [drush archive](https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/core/archive-dump/) for a complete backup (including files):

```
drush ard
```

Use [drush sql-dump](https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/sql/sql-dump/) to backup only the database:

```
drush sql-dump > /patch/to/new/file/with/db-dump
```